# SharePoint multiple user identities

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, windows-authentication

Can someone explain me please ... why has Sharepoint 2 different user identities for same user (i:0#.w|domain\username and domain\username) ? Because of this I have problem with my custom rights and with others.
Thank you.

Comment: The main problem is, when you have one user and you have got 2 different identities ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i:0#.w|domain\username** means this is encoded as claims. More about this encoding check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx).

You can check [this](https://luiscarrazana.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/how-to-decode-user-name-from-claims-format-in-sharepoint-2013/) article to see how handle this.

Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677722/why-do-i-get-i0-wdomain-username-and-within-runwithelevatedprivileges-domain) why this happens.

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have this problem with common users

Comment: Check if this can help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a2361efd-92a3-4e21-a1f5-3c32bc08262f/duplicate-name-of-the-trusted-identity-provider-in-people-picker?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 Authentication in SharePoint

**Windows claims authentication**

- First user will request web page(anonymous)
- Then request checks windows credentials with Active Directory
- And that Windows credentials to SharePoint

**Forms-based claims authentication**

- First user will request web page(anonymous)
- Send SharePoint forms-based login page
- Send credentials to Active Directory
- It will Validate the credentials with Membership provider

For More reference [Click Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219571.aspx)